# How to git clone via ssh without having to type in a password?

Tags: git, authentication, ssh

I am using a git repo over ssh but the ssh server is only configured for username / password authentication there is **no way** for me to configure authentication with this server using certificates.

So when I do a clone operation such as `ssh://user@host/git/demo.git` git asks me for a password to clone the repo.

I want to avoid having to type the password so I tried executing the following command based on another StackOverflow question on how to avoid having to type the password with https

```
git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=86400"
```

However the password I type is not getting cached.

I have to merge 20 different git repos into one big git repo and I want to write a shell script to do this so I don't want to have to keep typing my password.

Is there a way to pass the password to git from within a bash shell script? I am using git 1.8.5.1 on CentOS 6.5

Comment: Can you just use standard SSH key authentication?

Comment: You might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect and http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

Comment: `there is no way for me to configure authentication with this server using certificates.` If this is also specifically referring to key auth, then (based on my experience with `sshd`) I *believe* you're out of luck, since it requires some sort of authentication on every connection.

Comment: see [Generating Your SSH Public Key](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)

Comment: Where is the git server hosted? Could you have git repos served over http? (for example, github allows for cloning repos via http)

Comment: @JamesKingsbery the git repo is managed by a group within a huge multinational so getting any changes to how the git repos are setup is not practical.

Comment: down voter can you please explain why you are down voting? or voting to close the question?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this is to use a git client made for programmatic access. I've never used it before, but something like https://github.com/gordonwritescode/Nougit could do it.